# Need to launch website from portal codebehind web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core

I have several backoffice applications. One is meant to be a portal to the others.
Into the portal, I have the homepage who list all others application as link and when cliking on those link, I need to lauch new website to the linked application.

Over all of that, linked application waits for some parameters from portal.

For now, I have creatd simple  links with href to applications URL. It works well, but parameters are passed into query string.

For security reasons, I whish to hide parameters to customers, so the idea, will be to launch the application through ajax call either directly in JS or calling method in code behind.

For now, I have no clear idea on how to proceed on that. Is someone already did something like that? And it is only feasable?

Comment: You can add parameters as HTTP Header(s) instead of the URL.  There are standard and custom headers.  You probably want a custom header.

Comment: If it's all on the same domain, or you have control over the the cross-domain policies, you could use cookies.

Comment: If you absolutely need/want to copletely hide the parameters from the user, you need to make the call from the backend. Your links should point to addresses within your portal, and those addresses need to "assemble" the link (parameters and all) in code behind and then make a redirect to that link